# Заголовки столбцов в группах

Tags: datagrid, c#, wpf, .net

Ребят, честно искал два дня на наших и заграничных ресурсах - так и не нашёл, как сделать, чтобы при группировке строк в DataGrid в каждой группе отображались заголовки столбцов.

Группировка делал по примеру [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff407126%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Хочу перейти на WPF - как я понял, возможности у него огромные, но как эти возможности использовать, ещё не разобрался.

Может быть, кто знает хорошие бесплатные компоненты DataGrid? Лучше, если есть исходники, в которых можно поковыряться и найти нужное. Буду очень признателен.

**Уточнение вопроса:**
Почему в приведённом ниже примере стиля шаблон не выводит заголовки столбцов при указании DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter? 
Или нужно указать другой элемент шаблона для этого?

Пример стиля группы для моего DataGrid:

```
  <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
    <GroupStyle>
      <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,5"/>
          <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
              <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                <Expander IsExpanded="False" 
                            BorderBrush="#FF444E5F" 
                            BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" 
                            Padding="3,0,0,1">
                  <Expander.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                      <GradientStop Color="#eceff1" Offset="0"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#b0bec5" Offset="0.1"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#78909c" Offset="0.9"/>
                      <GradientStop Color="#455a64" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                  </Expander.Background>
                  <Expander.Header>
                    <DockPanel>
                      <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" 
                                   Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                                   Margin="5,0,5,0" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                      <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" 
                                   Text="(кол-во: " 
                                   Width="auto" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                      <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" 
                                   Text="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" 
                                   Width="auto" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                      <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" 
                                   Text=")" 
                                   Width="auto" 
                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                  </Expander.Header>
                  <Expander.Content>
                    <StackPanel>
                      <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Height="25"/>
                      <ItemsPresenter />
                    </StackPanel>
                  </Expander.Content>
                </Expander>
              </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
    </GroupStyle>
  </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте установить `GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate`, как указано в вашем примере из MSDN.

Comment: В примере MSDN второй GroupStyle указывается для установки стиля второго уровня группировки. Это - если нужно чтобы вложенные группы отличались внешне от родительских.
К сожалению, добавить заголовки столбцов внутри групп это не помогает.